# ios uploading data in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, upload

I'm working on a application where users can work online and offline (no network connection or server unavailable). Data has to be send a few hours after the user write them or they become obsolete.
When online, data are send to our server directly without problem. 
When offline, we wait to be online again to send the data and it works great when the application is in foreground. But when the application is in background we can't find any solution.
We tried to use the background fetch api but you can't control when it get executed and most of the times it's executed too late for us.
Is there a way to upload data frequently when the app is in background ?

Comment: What causes the data to be send again ? Is there any specific trigger e.g location change ? Or it's just a regular call to fetch something instead of upload ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good way is regularly make a push notification from your server and to catch that push notification. And you can run your upload/fetch code in application:didReceiveRemoteNotification or application:didReceiveLocalNotification methods in application delegate class.